# How can I configure a dynamic virtual host on Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have multiple development branches of my app, which I would like to be able to deploy on my testing server and switch between easily.

I was wondering about configuring some sort of dynamic virtual host so that on the web server I have:

```
/myApp/branch1
/myApp/branch2
/myApp/branch3
```

Which I can access via:

```
http://myapp.example.com/1/
http://myapp.example.com/2/
http://myapp.example.com/3/
```

The idea being that I can upload new branches and the virtual host will know how to serve those.

How can I do this?

Disclaimer: My knowledge of virtual hosts is limited; I would appreciate clear and simple instructions that I can learn from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the hostnames in the URL are the same as in your example (myapp.example.com), then all you need is a single host (main or virtual, it doesn't matter) with a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(\d+)/  /myApp/branch$1
```

See [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

If the hostnames are different, then you could use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) to to configure multiple virtual hosts at once.  For example to map branch1.example.com to /myApp/branch1,

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /myApp/%1
```

where `%1` picks up the first part of the hostname, or `branch1` in this example.

Comment: I've not used mod_rewrite with virtual hosts before. Where do I put the rewrite rule within the virtual host configuration? Could you give me a solution for doing this with dynamic subdomains instead? e.g. Where the host name is branch1.example.com?

Comment: You don't need a virtual host at all; answer clarified for that.  If you are using a virtual host, put the RewriteRule inside its configuration.